# Android PlacePicker API IntentBuilder location confirmation dialog

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, gmsplacepicker

I want to remove a confirmation dialog from Android PlacePicker API, is it possible?

[image]

Comment: sorry but how to get the image URL  inside the dialog ?

Comment: did you got the solution

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to disable the confirmation step in the Place Picker.

Comment: Does it change since then ? It's still not possible to disable/override the confirmation step ? I would like to use the Place Autocomplete as search bar in order to show the selected place in the map before setting this place as the selected one!